# what is algorithm of photoshop for converting rgb to cmyk as percentage?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, colors, rgb, cmyk

what is algorithm of photoshop for converting rgb to cmyk as percentage ?

for example:

```
R   G   B      C    M    Y    K
0   0   0   => 75%  68%  67%  90%
3   0   0   => 100% 100% 100% 100%
149 91  56  => 32%  65%  84%  21% 
255 255 255 => 0%   0%   0%   0%
```

I'm using javascript

Comment: I must use color converting in javascript and cant use .net apies!!

Comment: Math is math. Just because it's ASP doesn't mean 1+1=2 suddenly changes to 1+1=3 in javascript.

Comment: It uses .net api !! now how can I use .net apies in javascript ??!! photoshop uses some mathes to make conversions and that .net api use same but now my question is that what math methods this photoshop or .net apies uses to convert rgb to cmyk ??!!!

Comment: rgb value / 2.55 = % value

Comment: @jeffrbauer I want cmyk values in % mode not rgb values !! I have rgb and want to convert to cmyk and then to % like photoshop !! please see here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938896/how-convert-rgb-or-cmyk-color-to-percentage-cmyk-javascript) and help me there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RGB is converted to CMYK and vice versa by profile through CIE-Lab values.

CIE-Lab is a kind of "universal" color space connected to what people see by eyes.

Color properties of R, G and B values are contained in concrete RGB profile, and CMYK properties are contained in concrete CMYK profile as well as method how situations when one color can be obtained by different CMYK combinations should be resolved.

Some profiles have formulas, some profiles have interpolation matrix obtained by calibration.